# Choose a groupe (local/export) before registrate magento 2

Tags: magento2, register

I want to have in this page above create An Account 2 buttons and according to my choice  i will be redirected to different form of registration after clic on create account :[image]

So how to do that help please

Comment: Do you want to add radio option above `Create an account` and based on choice render different registration form ?

Comment: yes that 's it Pawan